# Writing simple single field javascript login form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, redirect, authentication

Hello I need help with a simple JavaScript log in form. I am building a small website for me and my classmates. I want it to be able to redirect each user to a specific page when a corresponding passcode is entered.

I know it is unsafe but we don't plan on keeping valuable information on the site. I don't know about MSQL and don't even wish to use it. The code works at this level but am unable to add users since I don't understand JavaScript. Thanks in advance.

```
/*here is the code i got so far*/ 

<title> 
    Enter Passcode to proceed 
</title> 
<h1 style="font-family:Comic Sans Ms; text-align="center"; font-size:20pt; color:#00FF00;> 
</h1> 
<form name="login"> 
    Passcode: <input type="text" name="userid"/> 
    <input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/> 
    <input type="reset" value="Cancel"/> 
</form> 
<script language="javascript"> 
    function check(form)/*function to check userid */ 
    { 
        /*the following code checkes whether the entered userid is correct*/ 
        if(form.userid.value == "JohnDoe") 
        { 
            window.open("johndoe.php")/*opens the target page while Id */ 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            alert("Invalid Passcode, please try again!")/*displays error message*/ 
        } 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `Comic Sans Ms` sigh...

Comment: i'm commenting here rather than answering, because i'm not providing a javascript solution, but... have you considered `.htaccess`? it's as secure as any other authentication technique but super easy to set up. [here's a quick (3 paragraphs)](http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/password-protection/) guide.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your current if condition that contains a search for a user.  Your else condition tells the user the passcode was invalid.  Between them add some `else if`'s.  Also, boo for comic sans and also there are quite a few more methods that would work.  You could, for example, post the form to a server-side script with hardcoded users there, and the viewer wouldn't be able to view source to get the info.

```
    if(form.userid.value == "JohnDoe") 
    { 
        window.open("johndoe.php")/*opens the target page while Id */ 
    }
```